# why memory access only once for accessing array's elements

Tags: c, arrays, memory, stack, memory-address

I was reading a textbook says that it only need one memory access when accessing an array's element? I don't quite get it especially when it is associated with assembly language and stack, let say we declare an array

```
char arr[3] = {'a','b','c'};
```

Lets say on the stack, first array's element a's address on the stack is 8 (I know it shoud be hex 0x...., for simplicity's sake), so b's address is 9, c is 10, so variable arr holds value of 8(first element's address) and arr itself address is something like 100. so to get the second element of the array:

1. we get the arr's holding value which is 8 (this is the first memory access as we get the value of arr, isn't it? )
2. once we have the address 8, then we offset 1 to get address 9, then we read this address's value(second memory access, so why the textbook says it only need one memory access)?
3. when we declare the array, is the values(a, b,c) pushed to the stack first or the point variable arr is pushed to the stack first?

Comment: You assumed `arr` needs to exist at address `100`. That's a baseless assumption.

Comment: You can read several bytes in 1 memory access ; e.g. on 32-bit CPU it's normal to do a 32-bit read

Comment: It's hard to follow your broken English, but I think you're asking about how arrays are stored and accessed in memory. That's a very architecture- and implementation-specific thing. Most modern architectures have many addressing modes so they can access stack-relative addresses easily for variables declared auto, and index registers that make it easy for variables declared static. Very rarely should it be necessary to store the actual address of an array in memory anywhere.

Comment: @StoryTeller   yes I know, it can exist in your reasonable address, but array's address is not important in the context, isn't it?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker sorry for the hard understanding, so what's the value of arr in  modern architectures? I understand assembly language a little bit, so do you mean arr is not saved on the stack?

Comment: "arr" is a symbol the compiler uses to refer to some piece of memory--it might be a stack offset, it might be a physical ram address. But the compiler will generate appropriate code to access it--its address is not necessarily stored anywhere at runtime. Compile some code and look at the assembly generated. Why ask us humans when you can get the answer from the source?

Comment: Dump the assembly code generated by your program. I suspect you will find access to each element uses a single - `lea` instruction (*load effective address*). In that case, the single-access is correct.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  yes there was lea instruction like lea arr(%eax...) which is arr + offset address, but I don't understand that arr seems to be 8, which means that arr has been memory access to get value of 8

Comment: `lea` is a special function that can compute+load. So instead of 2 instruction 1 for offset and 2 to load, lea does it all in one. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. There will be two memory access.

But what textbooks mean by single memory access is that once you have value of arr (the memory address from where array starts) and you know the offset, you require only one memory access, unlike in data structure like linked list where you will have to make 3 calls.

For your other question, first the array will be allocated the memory. This will happen as soon as the scope of this array begins, and when it reaches the particular command, the values will be copied to the allocated address.

Comment: What if `LEA` is used? That would be a single-instruction and single access.

Comment: You're neither wrong nor right--it's entirely up to the compiler/architecture.

Comment: @Vimarsh  thats not what the text book mean, the textbook is comparing multi level array(one memory access) and multi dimension array(two memory access)